# WinSCP exit codes

Tags: exit-code, winscp

I am scripting WinSCP into a VB.NET project and wondering is there a list of exit codes 
and descriptions I can use for error handling? Checked their site but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Actualyl scratch that ... only ExitCodes returned are 0 success and 1 error.

Comment: The answer below is correct. How come it is not marked?

Answer (score 1):

0 = success, 1 = error.

Refer here:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#result
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_result